# In Terraform, is it possible to get the log as json?

Tags: json, terraform

I would like to log all terraform operations in our organisation. 
For Example:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  ~ aws_instance.created_instance_record[0]
      disable_api_termination: "true" => "false"
      tags.V_Recepies:         "role[af-base], recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]n" => ""run_list":["role[af-base]","recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]"]"

  ~ aws_instance.created_instance_record[1]
      disable_api_termination: "true" => "false"
      tags.V_Recepies:         "role[af-base], recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]n" => ""run_list":["role[af-base]","recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]"]"

  ~ aws_instance.created_instance_record[2]
      disable_api_termination: "true" => "false"
      tags.V_Recepies:         "role[af-base], recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]n" => ""run_list":["role[af-base]","recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]"]"


Plan: 0 to add, 3 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Right now we collect the output in a shell script and push to slack. I want to collect this and send to ELK, but in order for this to make sense, I need json output, or something similar, that would look like this:

```
{
    [ 
        { 
            object: aws_instance, 
            disable_api_termination: "true" => "false", 
            tags: 
                [V_Recepies: "role[af-base], recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]n" => ""run_list":["role[af-base]","recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]"]"]

        },
        { 
            object: aws_instance, 
            disable_api_termination: "true" => "false", 
            tags: 
                [V_Recepies: "role[af-base], recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]n" => ""run_list":["role[af-base]","recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]"]"]

        },
        { 
            object: aws_instance, 
            disable_api_termination: "true" => "false", 
            tags: 
                [V_Recepies: "role[af-base], recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]n" => ""run_list":["role[af-base]","recipe[af-elasticsearch-6]"]"]

        }
    ]

}
```

I saw Terraform has json output, but only for some of the things.
Is the any way to turn TF logs into json ?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you maybe explain what sense you're trying to get out of Terraform here? It's not really something that lends well to being a structured log that is kept around for analysis in my opinion but maybe I'm missing what you're trying to do. If you could post the output you get currently and what you'd want then that would be useful.

Comment: will edit original post

Comment: It would help if you could mock out what that JSON output would look like and how that would be useful in ElasticSearch or even explain why you want this output to be kept for analysis.

Comment: edited original post

Comment: Unfortunately that's not doable in Terraform and I can't even see an easy way to transform things like you want. You could try raising a feature request for this on [GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues) but I'm not sure if there will be much interest in working in this unless you can provide a more solid reasoning for why you think you need this.